# Executing command prompt's functionality using Win32

Tags: c++, c, winapi

What Windows API functions are available to execute command prompt's functionality? For example, I like to execute dir command and want to show the output in GUI without using cmd.exe in Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start `cmd /c dir S:\ome\Path` from your process and grab the output. Otherwise it's not possible. But if you're not interested in particular formatting details of `dir` then you're probably better off just enumerating files/directories and display them.

Comment: That should be cmd /k dir, otherwise cmd will not exit after completing the dir command.

Comment: exactly vice-versa. /k remains, /c doesn't. Just take a look at cmd /?

Answer (score 1):

The dir command is built into the cmd.exe, it's not a separate executable. There's no way of executing it short of running cmd.exe.

EDIT: As for the displaying of results, you need to fill in the STARTUPINFO.hStdXXX members, probably using an anonymous pipe. See [this example](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10387).

Answer (score 0):

For a console app you can use **popen()**, but things are by no means so easy from a GUI app. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx for one approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a listing of files in a given folder see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c) which describes how to achieve it, using windows api or a more generic boost approach.

Answer (score 0):

Everything the Windows command line does is done through the Win32 APIs.

For example, with regard to "dir", FindFirstFile() and FindNextFile() will give you the contents of a directory.

For any given command, you will need to figure out which APIs/function calls are in use and then learn how to use them yourself in your own code.